# How to make SQL-injection proof calls to custom table I have created in my Wordpress Database?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, pagination

So here is what im trying to accomplish: I have worked with SQL plenty of times in the past, but it was always with coldfusion, never with PHP. I have looked over the syntax for making sql queries and have come up with this much (i do believe that using prepare helps protect against sql-injection). My overall goal is to have a page set up to where it pulls all the rows from the jewelry table that has the cat_id corresponding with the categories table. Im just not sure if im starting this off correctly or not. The jewelry table has 4 fields (id, cat id, name, and image)

```
<?php

 $categorys = $wpdb->get_results ( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM $wpdb->categories
        WHERE name = '(the_slug())'") );

    $jewelrys = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->jewelry
        WHERE post_status = 'publish'
        AND cat_id = $categorys->id ") );

    foreach ($jewelrys as $jewelry) {
    echo '<div id="jBox"><a href="/wp-includes/images/jewelryImages/' . $jewelry->image . '"><img src="/wp-includes/images/jewelryImages/' . $jewelry->image . '" /><br />' . $jewelry->name . '</div>';
    }
?>
```

Also i am looking to adding pagination displaying only 9 per page. Any tips or guidance is greatly appreciated =)

Update:
I just tested the category with a simple echo statement to see if it pulled anything, and it didn't, is this coded wrong?

Comment: +1 for being concerned about SQL injection!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid SQL injection, use prepared statements - that way you can pass your variable terms to MySQL as parameters (which it knows not to evaluate for SQL) rather than making them part of your SQL command.

See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

To implement pagination, you want to look into MySQL's `LIMIT` clause - e.g.

```
SELECT ... LIMIT  0,9;  -- get 9 records starting from record 0
SELECT ... LIMIT  9,9;  -- get 9 records starting from record 9
SELECT ... LIMIT 18,9;  -- get 9 records starting from record 18
-- etc
```

Comment: haha i know, havent had a chance to log back on here, sorry about that! yes this helped me out alot, i tend to program myself into a corner sometimes =P